# Why am I getting the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is of an illegal type: org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, executor

i want to press a key with JavascriptExecutor.For this I have created a class and a static method.

```
    private static JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)BrowserFactory.getDriver();

public static void clickButton(BaseElement element){
    jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element.getLocator());
}
```

But when in my PageObject method I call the button click, I get an error

```
    public void clickForJsAlertButton() {
    ScriptManager.clickButton(elementButton);
}

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is of an illegal type: org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath
```

I do not understand why this is happening and what needs to be done to fix it

Answer (score 2):

jsExecutor - only works with WebElement

```
    public static void clickButton(By locator){
    WebElement element = BrowserFactory.getDriver().findElement(locator);
    jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
}
```